# single page web crawl in PHP

Tags: php, html, phpcrawl

I am new to PHP. Can someone help me figure out how to crawl single html page and print all the words in the source code of that page?

Comment: What do you mean by "Print all the words in the source code of that page"?

Comment: i mean .. to parse through the body of the page and print all the words of length more than 3 ..

Comment: Define word? are you talking about words in text? tags? it's very confusing

Comment: PHP.net has some good material on how to navigate the DOM using PHP @ http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: When you say "body of the page," do you literally mean the content between the `<body>` tags? And are HTML tags counted as part of "all the words"?

Comment: say if you open a wikipedia page.. i want to print all the words in the text that you see which are of a certain length..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$words = explode(" ", strip_tags(file_get_contents("www.example.com"));
function trim_and_print(&$value) 
{ 
    trim($value);
    if(strlen($value > 3) 
        echo $value;
}

array_walk($words, 'trim_and_print');
```

this should print words with length > 3. Thanks to moteutsch for file_get_contents

Comment: Why not use `file_get_contents`?

Comment: when i replace the line echo $buffer with echo strip_tags($buffer); I am getting empty page as output. But I need the words in the text of the source as the output.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but you would need to download the page (with either cURL or PHP's file functions) and process the file in some way. Here is a basic solution:

```
echo strip_tags(file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'));
```